# Оптимизация алгортима перебора пикселей WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Здравствуйте, есть метод получения массива яркостей из BitmapSource для дальнейшего анализа:

```
public const float CoeffColor = ((float)100 / 255 * 3) / 10000;
//...
arrayPixelsImage = new byte[SizeArrayPixels];
source.CopyPixels(arrayPixelsImage, StriteImage, 0); //typeof(source) == BitmapSource
float[,] massBrightness = new float[WidthImage, HeightImage];
Parallel.For(0, WidthImage, x =>
{
    for (int y = 0; y < HeightImage; y++)
    {
        int indx = y * WidthImage * 4 + 4 * x;
        float brightness = (float)(arrayPixelsImage[indx] + arrayPixelsImage[indx + 1] + arrayPixelsImage[indx + 2]) * CoeffColor;
        massBrightness[x, y] = brightness;
    }
});
return massBrightness;
```

Интересует то, как можно его оптимизировать, в плане времени выполнения?

Comment: ну, тут много вариантов "оптимизаций" можно накрутить. Вот например некоторый список который можно протестировать:
1) Внутренний цикл тоже сделать Parallel.For.. 
2) Отказаться вообще от вложенного цикла и сделать цикл элементам arrayPixelsImage
2.1) Можно на первых парах избавиться от необходимости расчёта измерений x и y у massBrightness сделав его одномерным и, соответственно равным по размерности arrayPixelsImage. (хотя если всё же нужен 2-х мерный массив то в этом особого выигрыша не будет)

Comment: @Alexey , если параллелить и вложенный то тогда время выполнения вырастает раза в 4. Да нужно именно 2-х мерный, если менять тут то менять придётся во всей программе, что убьёт читабельность

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Погонял алгоритм на fullHD jpeg'e. У меня на нём выходит чуть боле 2млн итераций суммарно.(внешний параллельный + внутренний) И тут, я боюсь оптимизировать особо не получится. 
Примерные затраты по коду:

`int indx = y * WidthImage * 4 + 4 * x;` -25%

`float brightness = (float)(arrayPixelsImage[indx] + arrayPixelsImage[indx + 1] + arrayPixelsImage[indx + 2]) * CoeffColor;` -70%

`massBrightness[x, y] = brightness;`-3%

сам цикл -2%

Учитывая общее кол-во итераций не лишним будет отметить, что накладные расходы на создание нового таска на каждой итерации Parallel.For практически нивелируют выигрыш от использования распараллеливания при сравнении с последовательным циклом с таким же кол-вом итераций. Т.е. цикл с 2М итераций с тем же телом выполняется почти за то же кол-во тиков.

Резюмируя свои мысли по поводу оптимизации данного кода:

На C# вряд ли удастся достичь хотя бы 2-х кратного прироста производительности. Можно оптимизировать все вычисления и операции доступа/присвоения, но максимум, чего удастся добиться это 30% прироста на "удачном" прогоне по отношению к среднему результату до оптимизации. Если учесть что винда система отнюдь не реального времени то даже оптимизированный вариант может ( и достаточно часто будет) отрабатывать дольше чем средне время для не оптимизированного варианта.

Если нужно "лопатить" большие объёмы данных и по другому никак при этом выполняя на каждом кванте  (единице данных) достаточно простые/быстрые операции то я рекомендую смотреть вам в сторону использования ресурсов GPU (OpenCL или CUDA)

Для всех остальных случаев я бы смотрел в сторону упрощения алгоритма или уменьшения числа операций. Например понижал бы разрешение изображения пока это не сильно сказывается на результате. Ощутимо упростить что-либо в этих 3-х строчках кода вряд ли получится. Поэтому думайте как уменьшить число итераций.

Answer (score 1):

```
writeableBitmap.Lock();
/* 
в отдельных потоках выполняете обработку.
дожидаетесь завершения потоков.
*/
writeableBitmap.AddDirtyRect(...);
writeableBitmap.Unlock();
```

также посмотрите реализацию методов в проекте [Microsoft Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D)

Answer (score 0):

1. Заменить Parallel.For на более быстрый вариант:

   OrderablePartitioner> Partitioner1 = Partitioner.Create(0, WidthImage);
   Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner1, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1 }, (range, loopState) =>
                           {
                               for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
                               {
                                   ...
                               }
                           });
2. Развернуть внутренний цикл хотя бы на 2 одновременно обрабатываемых значения двух соседних пикселей. За счёт экономии чтений из памяти возможен прирост. У меня такое работало.
3. По возможности float заменить на ushort, если его диапазона будет достаточно по точности. Так же мною был замечен прирост производительности при этом.

Алгоритм изначально слишком прост, что даже нет пространства для манёвров. Если это абсолютно всё, что требуется в программе, то, наверно, копать некуда, а если делается ещё что-то, то есть смысл свести обработку в один цикл. Если вариантов обработки несколько, то есть смысл написать несколько алгоритмов под каждый случай.

Для видеокарты такие простые алгоритмы бессмысленны. Там весь эффект скушает перемещение данных на карту и обратно. Если только массивы будут одни и те же, а меняются только некоторые входные параметры.

Если это функция какого-то более сложного алгоритма, то естественно её нужно встраивать в основной алгоритм. Когда нужна производительность, стоит забыть про читабельность кода и прочие рюшечки.